# Disable subtitle (AsciiDoc PDF output)

Tags: maven, pdf, asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

Is there any way to disable the subtitle when generating a PDF with AsciiDoc? The thing is that I want to keep the subtitle within the HTML output but not within the PDF output.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

PS: I'm using the Maven plugin for AsciiDoc.